# Why does GCL immediately die when I try to start it?

Tags: common-lisp, gnu-common-lisp

Why does GCL (GNU Common Lisp) immediately die when I try to start it?

```
user@host:~$ gcl
Killed
user@host:~$
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This often happens when GCL is compiled as super user and then run as a non-super user.  This is because GCL optimizes for more heap space.  This can be addressed in one of two ways:

1. Compile as a normal user, then install GCL as a super user or
2. Update your system to allow non-super users to start at a lower address space with the command.
   `sudo /sbin/sysctl vm.mmap_min_addr=0`

   You'll also need to make it persist beyond boot.